# Get Transaction Id after completing Payment Objective c?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, paypal

I was trying to get transation Id when paypal payment is done that is on  didCompletePayment method, i can get only these details

```
 Confirmation: {
    client =     {
        environment = sandbox;
        "paypal_sdk_version" = "2.12.2";
        platform = iOS;
        "product_name" = "PayPal iOS SDK";
    };
    response =     {
        "create_time" = "2017-02-01T07:40:43Z";
        id = "PAY-4RK70135CF912010FLCIZB5A";
        intent = sale;
        state = approved;
    };
    "response_type" = payment;
}
```

I don't find transation ID here. Can any one suggest me how to get transation Id in detail so that i can save that to database.
I found some Curl concepts but i'm not sure where to start with.Please give me some suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are getting id in response dictionary of your response i.e. id = "PAY-4RK70135CF912010FLCIZB5A"; which is your Transection ID.

Comment: Transaction id we get is 16 digit number/digits which is not PayId